# Can we modify "Send Alerts To " field to add/remove users from existing alerts

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, administration, alert, sharepoint-alerts

I have created an alert and i defined 3 users (including myself) to receive the alerts:-

[image]

but after creating the alerts I noticed the following 2 issues:

1. if I edit the alert I can not add/remove users from the "Send alerts to" field.

[image]

2. also if I remove the alert from my user, it will not remove them from the 2 users' alerts

is this how alerts work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you click on "Manage my alerts" from SharePoint list, it will only show your alerts on the SharePoint site:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_layouts/15/mysubs.aspx
```

If you are site admin and you want to delete alerts for other users, follow this:

1. Go to Site Settings page
2. Select "User alerts" under "Site Administration" (`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_layouts/15/sitesubs.aspx`)
3. To select a user, select **Display alerts for**, and then select **Update**.
4. Next to the alert you want to delete, select the checkbox, and then select **Delete Selected Alerts**.
5. Select **OK**.

[image]

**Documentation**: [Manage, view, or delete SharePoint alerts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2#ID0EBJ=Modern)